# Delete & Insert new data into table

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-insert, sql-delete, execution

I need to delete old records and insert new records on a daily basis as item events change.  I am trying to get a list of every item by location that is not in liquidation and be able to update it everyday so I created a table to delete & Insert:

Items_minus_liquidation (table name)

(Store A INTEGER NULL,

Store B INTEGER NULL)

Table A:

```
LOCATION      EVENT         ITEM
STORE A    LIQUIDATION     APPLE
STORE A      SALE          BANANA
STORE A      SALE          ORANGE
STORE A      SALE          PEAR
STORE A    LIQUIDATION     PEACH
STORE A      SALE          SPINACH
STORE A      SALE          TOMATO
STORE A    LIQUIDATION     CARROT
STORE A      SALE         BROCCOLI
STORE A      SALE         MUSHROOM
STORE B    LIQUIDATION     APPLE
STORE B      SALE          BANANA
STORE B      SALE          ORANGE
STORE B      SALE          PEAR
STORE B    LIQUIDATION     PEACH
STORE B      SALE          PLUM
STORE B      SALE         TOMATO
STORE B    LIQUIDATION    CARROT
STORE B      SALE         BROCCOLI
STORE B      SALE         MUSHROOM
```

Here is the result I am looking for:

```
STORE_A    STORE_B
BANANA     BANANA
ORANGE     ORANGE
PEAR       PEAR
SPINACH    NULL
NULL       PLUM
TOMATO     TOMATO
BROCCOLI   BROCCOLI
MUSHROOM   MUSHROOM
```

Here is my current Query:

```
DELETE FROM DB.ITEMS_MINUS_LIQUIDATION;
INSERT INTO DB.ITEM_MINUS_LIQUIDATION
SELECT
    A.PRODUCT AS STORE_A,
    B.PRODUCT AS STORE_B
FROM
(
SELECT
    ITEM AS PRODUCT
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE EVENT NOT IN  ('LIQUIDATION')
AND LOCATION='STORE_A'
) A

FULL OUTER JOIN

(
SELECT
    ITEM AS PRODUCT
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE EVENT NOT IN  ('LIQUIDATION')
AND LOCATION='STORE_B'
) B

ON A.ITEM=B.ITEM
```

The issue is the INSERT command runs and runs and runs without ever providing any results.  The full outer join query results in exactly what I am looking for above, so I am hoping to delete old records and insert new records with the full outer join query.  Why is the insert command not working properly?

Comment: Did you mean to have two different table names ? DB.ITEMS_MINUS_LIQUIDATION; and DB.ITEM_MINUS_LIQUIDATION

Comment: When I run into a problem like this I start paring down my query to identify the root cause. Start by running INSERT without the DELETE statement, then INSERT data without your FULL OUTER JOIN (try both separately). Then INSERT without the WHERE clauses. Once you figure out which part of the query is the problem you can attempt to resolve it. Also try running sp_who2 in another window while this query is running, if that doesn't yield information... try SQL Profiler.

Comment: @JacobH: `sql` doesn't mean *MS SQL Server*, this question is based on *Teradata*, there's no SQL Profiler...

Comment: Are those ITEMs unique?

Comment: No they are meant to be the same table name.  @dnoeth - yes these items are unique, I scaled back the total data set as its much larger.  Is there a SQL Profiler equivalent for Teradata?

Comment: Can you show the actual query and/or Explain? There's Viewpoint's QueryMonitor (while the query s running) or QueryLog data (after the query finished).

Comment: @dnoeth - I am unable to share the exact query, but the one above is essentially the same thing.  Basically I want every item by store that are not in liquidation, I'm sure there is a more basic way to write the query.

Comment: When the combination `location/item` is unique your query is correct, another solution would be `SELECT 
   Min(CASE WHEN LOCATION='STORE A' THEN item END) AS STORE_A,
   Min(CASE WHEN LOCATION='STORE B' THEN item END) AS STORE_B
FROM tab
WHERE EVENT NOT IN ('LIQUIDATION')
GROUP BY 
   Coalesce(
      CASE WHEN LOCATION='STORE A' THEN item END,
      CASE WHEN LOCATION='STORE B' THEN item END)` Can you share the Explain (search&replace table/column names)?